# Download a file created in the Pyodide file system

Tags: javascript, python, pyodide

I'm using Pyodide and I have several files in the Pyodide file system.
I try to implement the following behavior :

- the user click on a button to download a specific file from the Pyodide file system
- the download starts

The file to be downloaded is a zip file.

I read the file with:

```
let file = pyodide.FS.readFile('/home/pyodide/assets/test.zip', { encoding: "utf8" });
```

And I try to save it with `FileSaver.js` :

```
saveAs(file, 'test.zip');
```

But the download doesn't work.

Comment: The browser knows nothing about the Pyodide file system or Python functions such as `saveAs`. Python/PyScript knows nothing about the desktop local file system. You must load the file into memory, convert it into a JavaScript `Blob` and then call a browser function to write to the local desktop file system. I wrote a series of articles on Pyscript, Pyodide, file systems and JavaScript Interop that will show you how: https://www.jhanley.com/blog/category/pyscript/